# saving div layout/tables with content via c# or JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I have some JavaScript that on button click takes a the text from the textarea and places it into a div.

What I would like to do preferably via C# is save that content (somehow) to a textdoc maybe? or straight into the database (unsure as it could contain alot). So unfimilar with JavaScript hence my preference for C but if JavaScript could do the job it would be nice to have the client side run the script.

Atm all I want to do is save the divs somehow then later I will learn how to retrieve them.

The JavaScript I have atm for creating the div:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('button').click(function () {
            var x = $('textarea').val();
            $('textarea').val('');
            $('#test1').append('<div id="test">' + x + '</div>');
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

which outputs:

```
<div id="test1">
<div id="test">Write Something....</div>
<div id="test">Write Something....</div>
</div>
```

As you can see there can be many of the same type but if I could just save that data then i could find a way to load it later!

Comment: very sorry im a weekend warrior just had to read up on the differences lol

Comment: I don't get your question. Do you want to save the data in your database, or just output it in a div ?

Comment: no it already outputs (this is my own version of a wall posting system) I need to find a way to save the data on the wall (divs/html) then load them again if the user logs in but atm i just want to learn how its possible saving html content to a document or db of some kind?

Comment: and then later load that content back into the page when the user logs back in!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use XMLHTTPRequests -  also known as AJAX, to do this. (Read about AJAX [here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp))

Through jQuery's $.ajax or $.post function, you can send this HTML to a server-side script (PHP, ASP, etc.) and have that script save it to your database. I recommend using javascript to strip out newlines, etc...

Of course, there's also cookies, but that is very impractical and not a good idea. Cookies only exist as long as the user allows them to.

Comment: isn't this what I answered ? :3

Comment: dont have a clue how to do that, there must be a much more simpler way of saving the html part of a aspx page and loading it on new sessions? (straight from the database) I mean even if I have to write it in the pageload and have auto postback it would be much more simpler?

Comment: ...No...o_O Data doesn't just stay, because the develper nicely asks :P If you want this to be an efficient, well-working project, you will NEED to save it to a database. Since you are using ASP, LMGTFY. http://tinyurl.com/6yv6de5

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to save the informations somewhere.

You can do it in the Cookies (not recommended) or in your database (recommended).

To save it in your database, you can do a regular POST with a  **OR** submit the data via AJAX to your C# script that will do the magic with the database.

Comment: to save the form data in your database ?